# Delphi and using Teamspeak SDK parsing arrays to DLL

Tags: c++, arrays, delphi

When connecting to a TeamSpeaker server you can specify a list of default channels to join, I'm looking for how to build a list of channels names and parse it to the dll in the startConnection.

No need to think about the error handling, it's fine for now.

Two things, I assume the so called array must be one consecutive chunk of memory so the mem allocation must be done in one operation, then that chunk is just a bunch of pointers to other chunks of memory allocations representing the data, the receiver need to know what data types the memory holds to be able to put the data back into some defined understandable datatypes like string, integer etc. is that about right?

But what kind of memory allocation must/can I use for this and can I free that chunk right after the method call returns, caller owns the memory when nothing else is stated?

How can I build, populate and parse Array[] of string into the below defaultChannelArray?

**const defaultChannelArray: PPAnsiChar;**

Connect to a TeamSpeak 3 server with

```
function ts3client_startConnection(serverConnectionHandlerID: uint64;
  const identity: PAnsiChar;
  const ip: PAnsiChar; port: longword;
  const nickname: PAnsiChar;
  const defaultChannelArray: PPAnsiChar;
  const defaultChannelPassword: PAnsiChar;
  const serverPassword: PAnsiChar): longword; cdecl; external CLIENT_DLL {$IFDEF MACOS}
name '_ts3client_startConnection' {$ENDIF};

unsigned int ts3client_startConnection(serverConnectionHandlerID, identity, ip,
  port, nickname, defaultChannelArray, defaultChannelPassword, serverPassword);
uint64 serverConnectionHandlerID;
const char * identity;
const char * ip;
unsigned int port;
const char * nickname;
const char * * defaultChannelArray;
const char * defaultChannelPassword;
const char * serverPassword;
```

Parameters
• serverConnectionHandlerID 
Unique identifier for this server connection. Created with ts3client_spawnNewServerConnectionHandler
• identity
The clients identity. This string has to be created by calling ts3client_createIdentity. Please note an application should create the identity only once, store the string locally and reuse it for future connections.
• ip
Hostname or IP of the TeamSpeak 3 server.
If you pass a hostname instead of an IP, the Client Lib will try to resolve it to an IP, but the function may block for an unusually long period of time while resolving is taking place. If you are relying on the function to return quickly, we recommend to resolve the hostname  yourself (e.g. asynchronously) and then call ts3client_startConnection with the IP instead of the hostname.
• port
UDP port of the TeamSpeak 3 server, by default 9987. TeamSpeak 3 uses UDP. Support for TCP might be added in the future.
• nickname
On login, the client attempts to take this nickname on the connected server. Note this is not necessarily the actually assigned nickname, as the server can modifiy the nickname ("gandalf_1" instead the requested "gandalf") or refuse blocked names.
• defaultChannelArray
String array defining the path to a channel on the TeamSpeak 3 server. If the channel exists and the user has sufficient rights and supplies the correct password if required, the channel will be joined on login.
To define the path to a subchannel of arbitrary level, create an array of channel names detailing the position of the default channel (e.g. "grandparent", "parent", "mydefault", "").  The array is terminated with a empty string.
Pass NULL to join the servers default channel.
• defaultChannelPassword
Password for the default channel. Pass an empty string if no password is required or no default channel is specified.
• serverPassword
Password for the server. Pass an empty string if the server does not require a password.
All strings need to be encoded in UTF-8 format.
Returns ERROR_ok on success, otherwise an error code as defined in public_errors.h. When trying to connect with an invalid identity, the Client Lib will set the error  ERROR_client_could_not_validate_identity.

Example code to request a connection to a TeamSpeak 3 server:

```
unsigned int error;
uint64 scHandlerID;
char * identity;

error = ts3client_spawnNewServerConnectionHandler( & scHandlerID);
if (error != ERROR_ok) {
  printf("Error spawning server conection handler: %d\n", error);
  return;
}
error = ts3client_createIdentity( & identity); /* Application should store and reuse the identity */
if (error != ERROR_ok) {
  printf("Error creating identity: %d\n", error);
  return;
}
error = ts3client_startConnection(scHandlerID,
  identity "my-teamspeak-server.com",
  9987,
  "Gandalf",
  NULL, // Join servers default channel"", // Empty default channel password
  "secret"); // Server password
if (error != ERROR_ok) {
  (...)
}
ts3client_freeMemory(identity); /* Don't need this anymore */
```

Comment: FWIW, you use the term parse wrongly. Look it up. You mean pass rather than parse!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This array is input data. All the allocation issues are different from output arrays, the subject of your other recent questions.

In this case I would declare the array as a Delphi dynamic array:

```
var
  arr: TArray<PAnsiChar>;
```

Or if you use a pre-generics Delphi

```
var
  arr: array of PAnsiChar;
```

Allocate it:

```
SetLength(arr, N+1); // the +1 is for the nil
```

Initialise it:

```
for i := 0 to N-1 do
  arr[i] := PAnsiChar(str[i]); // I assume you have str[i] already, of type AnsiString
arr[N] := PAnsiChar('');
```

And then use

```
PPAnsiChar(arr)
```

as your argument to the function.

The convention used for input parameters is that references will not be taken unless explicitly stated. Feel free to deallocate your array once the function returns. Since dynamic arrays in Delphi are managed there is no explicit action required on your part.

Comment: Really, nooooooooo, it can't possible be that simple, it has got to complex.... LOL, okay joking, that's pretty straight forward.

Okay, so I've tested it and I get an AV when **passing** that array,

Comment: I should have read more closely. The array is terminated with empty string and not `NULL`. See the update. Please delete your non-answer.

Comment: Deleted 
  
 
I'm sorry, didn't know how else to add this code to the thread, the code was too long for the "add comments". I have noticed the run snippets - but they gets added when you chose to insert code using the tool buttons, and that's the only way I have found to keep a readable code formatting when posting

Comment: I missed that too

(e.g. "grandparent", "parent", "mydefault", ""). The array is terminated with a empty string.

Comment: I write the code, select it, and press CTRL+K. That indents the selection by 4 characters which makes it a code block.

Comment: Thanks David, you have really been very helpful.